# my java code gets compilation error.how to fix it?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class calculator {
    void add(float a, float b)
    {
        System.out.print("Result: "+(a+b));
    }
    void sub(float a, float b)
    {
        System.out.print("Result: "+(a-b));
    }
    void mult(float a, float b)
    {
        System.out.print("Result: "+(a*b));
    }
    void div(float a, float b)
    {
        System.out.print("Result: "+(a/b));
    }
}

class Cal {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Two Operands: ");
            float a=sc.nextFloat();

            float b=sc.nextFloat();

            System.out.print("Press 1 for Addition\n Press 2 for
            Subtraction\n Press 3 for Multiplication\n Press 4 for 
            Division\n Press 5 for Exit\n");

            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            calculator c=new calculator();
            switch(n)
            {
                case 1: c.add(a,b);
                        break;
                case 2: c.sub(a,b);
                        break;
                case 3: c.mult(a,b);
                        break;
                case 4: c.div(a,b);
                        break;
                case 5: System.exit(0);
                default: System.out.print("Wrong Choice!!!");
            }
            System.out.print("Are you want to continue?: ");
            int con=sc.nextInt();
        } while (con==1);
    }
}
```

It is simple calculator problem but I face below given error:

```
PS H:\java> javac calculator.java

calculator.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                }while(con==1);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable con
  location: class Cal
1 error
```

Comment: `con` is declared inside the loop, it is not visible outside of the loop .

Comment: Does your IDE not highlight this error?  Maybe use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ and you will find bugs like this easier.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `con` variable is declared inside the loop and not visible to `while`.

Declare `int con=0;` before `do-while` loop starts. and remove `int` from `con` value assignment in the loop.